# Django Move Project from Windows Host to Linux Host (and Deploy)

Tags: python, django, debugging, deployment, django-deployment

I'm trying to Move my Django App to a real Server (or deploy it there, self-hosted) but everything, I have tried so far, does nothing except displaying errors. I'm using the SQLite database because the app won't get much traffic at all.

For Example: If I try to deploy the app on my Windows machine I get security errors he won't pass.

```
py -3 manage.py check --deploy
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (security.W004) You have not set a value for the SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS setting. If your entire site is served only over SSL, you may want to consider setting a value and enabling HTTP Strict Transport Security. Be sure to read the documentation first; enabling HSTS
 carelessly can cause serious, irreversible problems.
?: (security.W008) Your SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT setting is not set to True. Unless your site should be available over both SSL and non-SS
L connections, you may want to either set this setting True or configure a load balancer or reverse-proxy server to redirect all connections to HTTPS.
?: (security.W018) You should not have DEBUG set to True in deployment.

System check identified 3 issues (0 silenced).
```

Even if I set Debug to False he won't pass the last two Security Checks. AND in Debug State False the Website even does not load correctly on my Windows machine...

[image]

Even the Django Admin Panel looks awful at this state...

[image]

If I try to run `run manage.py check --deploy` on the Linux server I get the exact same errors.

```
python3 Onboarding-Django/onboarding/manage.py check --deploy
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (security.W004) You have not set a value for the SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS setting. If your entire site is served only over SSL, you may want to consider setting a value and enabling HTTP Strict Transport Security. Be sure to read the documentation first; enabling HSTS carelessly can cause serious, irreversible problems.
?: (security.W008) Your SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT setting is not set to True. Unless your site should be available over both SSL and non-SSL connections, you may want to either set this setting True or configure a load balancer or reverse-proxy server to redirect all connections to HTTPS.
?: (security.W018) You should not have DEBUG set to True in deployment.

System check identified 3 issues (0 silenced).
```

And here is what confuses me the most. I've already adapted the settings.py Static Root and so on AND Django tells me that he is missing the Base_generic.html Template that is definitely there AND Django HAS Access to It. I don't get it at all.

[image]

Please help me. I worked month for this Project but if I can't deploy it the whole thing was for nothing...

More Information:

Windows Folders and settings.py

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found my Error.
There where a blank in the Green Box.
[image]