# Django How to Deploy Project pythonanywhere.com

Tags: python, django, github, pythonanywhere, django-deployment

this is the following question of this unanswered post:
[Django Move Project from Windows Host to Linux Host (and Deploy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972401/django-move-project-from-windows-host-to-linux-host-and-deploy)

I've tried to follow this How To this time:
https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/de/django_installation/ and
https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/de/deploy/#registriere-dich-f%C3%BCr-ein-pythonanywhere-konto

So I Uploaded my Code to Github and made it Publicly available and I created a pythonanywhere project at this URL:
http://mvanthiel.pythonanywhere.com/catalog/ui/

I also created a virtual environment and created the .gitignore file.

On my Windows (Dev) Host the Website does work as expected.
On pythonanywhere.com it does not.

On Windows Dev, I pushed the Projekt content to git like explained in the how-to.
On pythonanywhere.com I installed the pip module.
`pip3.6 install --user pythonanywhere`
And then I tried to autoconfigure the rest on pythonanywhere.com with:
`pa_autoconfigure_django.py --python=3.6 https://github.com/HigeMynx/onboarding.git`

after that, the Website is Online Available but exactly like described in my previous unanswered post, Django is missing the Template only on Linux Machines and i don't know why.

I can give you access to my pythonanywhere.com bash if needed, and you can look in my git code if needed.

Please help me with this.

Comment: You don't have to make your github repo public to deploy on pythonanywhere. Also, have you taken a look at pythonanywhere's [tutorial](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DeployExistingDjangoProject/) on deployment?

Comment: I have Templates in ``/catalog/templates/...`` and yes I did have a look at https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DeployExistingDjangoProject/.

Answer (score 0):

I found my Error. There where a blank in the Green Box. 
[image]